# Как из даты вычислить месяц Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue3

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <div>
      Дата: <input type="text" v-model="date"><br><br>
      
      -{{ date }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data (){
      return {
        date: '',
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать чтобы в место цифры месяца было короткое имя месяца

типа этого: 20ДЕК24

Comment: А как вы поняли, что 201224 это дата и что это 20 декабря 24, а не 24 декабря 20?
И почему вы выбрали type=text для даты, когда есть type=date? Получить имя месяца можно примерно так: `(new Date()).toLocaleString('ru', { month: 'short' });`

Comment: @Darth, спасибо за комментарий, я знаю что можно использовать type=date но в задании type=text потому что например если дата 01.01.1992 то в 
календаре нужно несколько раз кликать чтобы выбрать нужную дату
(new Date()).toLocaleString('ru', { month: 'short' }); этот код работает при type=text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал примерно так:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
        return {
            date: '',
        }
    },
    computed: {
        dateText(){
            const date = new Date(this.date);
            return `${date.getFullYear()}${date.toLocaleString('ru', {month:'short'})}${date.getDate()}`;
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
 <div id="app">
    <div>
      Дата: <input type="date" v-model="date" /><br/><br/>
      
      -{{ dateText }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ваш код работает идеально но когда я делаю type=text в textbox я должен делать 18.03.2024 точнее с точкой написать дату как сделать чтобы работало без точек типа этого 18032024, заранее спасибо

Comment: Вот тут есть длинный список валидных форматов строки для даты в js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript
Если вы хотите использовать другие форматы, которые он не понимает - вам нужно вручную разобрать свою входную строку на части и скормить в конструктор обьекта Date в одном из валидных вариантов